# 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown). It cannot perform a save operation.'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I am getting a crash at "try save()" this line.

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

/// Only save if `hasChanges`
func saveIfNeeded() throws {
    guard hasChanges else {
        return
    }

    do {
        try save()
    } catch {
        assertionFailure("Failed to save main context: \(error)")
        throw error
    }
}

/// Calls `saveIfNeeded` and then calls `saveIfNeededUpToRootContext()` on the `parentContext`.
func saveIfNeededUpToRootContext() throws {
    try saveIfNeeded()
    try parent?.saveIfNeededUpToRootContext()
}
```

}

In the appdelegte , appDidFinishLaunching : I have written :

```
defer {
            do {
                try DataStore.mainContext.saveIfNeededUpToRootContext()
            } catch {
                log("Failed to save \"App Feedback\" to Core Data: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

Basically calling the above method : saveIfNeededUpToRootContext.

Below is the initialisation of DataStore:

```
fileprivate let coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
let mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext
var isLoaded = false

init() {
    guard let model = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: nil) else {
        fatalError("No models in main bundle")
    }

    coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
    coordinator.name = "main_coordinator"

    mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    mainContext.name = "main_context"
    mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    mainContext.undoManager = nil

    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(save), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(save), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
}
```

Comment: `DataStore.mainContext` How is created `mainContext`? If you do `DataStore.mainContext.save()` do you still have the issue?

Comment: @Larme I am edited the question to include the DataStore object initialisation part.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: iPhone7 simulator 10.0

Comment: Trying to guess a possible situation - check if you have made changes in the existing data model version without adding a new version or forgot to set the current version as the new one.

Comment: If the new model is the reason, then resetting the simulator should solve the issue. I reset the simulator. But no luck.

Comment: And one update: @Larme, Larme's suggestion worked!! DataStore.mainContext.save() is working fine, problem is : If I use DataStore.mainContext.saveIfNeededUpToRootContext then the problem persists.

Comment: If you remove `try parent?.saveIfNeededUpToRootContext()` of `func saveIfNeededUpToRootContext() throws {`, does it work with `try DataStore.mainContext.saveIfNeededUpToRootContext()`. Your issue may be on `parent`.

Comment: @Larme I tried commenting : 
"try parent?.saveIfNeededUpToRootContext()" - this line.
But it did not help.

Comment: are you using multithreading?